# fasttext Installation in anaconda

Tags: python, pybind11, fasttext

I'm using Anaconda3-2024.02-1-Windows-x86_64 (yes, Windows 64) on windows 11, with python 3.11.7. I was trying to build an offline translator and i forgot what led to what... Eventually i was trying to install EasyNMT and it faild because of fasttext package. Then, I decided to install fasttext separately but failed and can't seem to know what the problem is. I am using pip on Anaconda Prompt to install almost all my packages. And I suffer from a weak internet connection. The code is below:

```
(base) C:\Users\pc>pip install wheel
Collecting fasttext
  Using cached fasttext-0.9.2.tar.gz (68 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\python.exe: No module named pip
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 38, in __init__
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybind11'

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-31ahp4pz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-31ahp4pz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-31ahp4pz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-31ahp4pz\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 72, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 41, in __init__
      RuntimeError: pybind11 install failed.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have just updated my MS Build Tools for Visual Studio because of another project.
I tried to install pybind11 on it's own. and it was already downloaded I guess.
pip install pybind11
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.11.1)

So!!!! I don't know what to do...... HELP ME PLEASE!!

UPDATE!!
I did start clean after the answer given below and everything went smoothly until I installed easyNMT and I got this error message:

```
(base) C:\Windows\System32>pip install -U easynmt
Collecting easynmt
  Using cached EasyNMT-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\users\pc\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from easynmt) (4.66.1)
Requirement already satisfied: transformers<5,>=4.4 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easynmt) (4.32.1)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.6.0 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easynmt) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\pc\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from easynmt) (1.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in c:\users\pc\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from easynmt) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sentencepiece in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easynmt) (0.2.0)
Collecting fasttext (from easynmt)
  Using cached fasttext-0.9.2.tar.gz (68 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from easynmt) (5.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch>=1.6.0->easynmt) (3.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.8.0 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch>=1.6.0->easynmt) (4.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch>=1.6.0->easynmt) (1.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch>=1.6.0->easynmt) (3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch>=1.6.0->easynmt) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: fsspec in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from torch>=1.6.0->easynmt) (2023.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: huggingface-hub<1.0,>=0.15.1 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers<5,>=4.4->easynmt) (0.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers<5,>=4.4->easynmt) (23.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.1 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers<5,>=4.4->easynmt) (6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: regex!=2019.12.17 in c:\users\pc\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from transformers<5,>=4.4->easynmt) (2023.12.25)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers<5,>=4.4->easynmt) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tokenizers!=0.11.3,<0.14,>=0.11.1 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers<5,>=4.4->easynmt) (0.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: safetensors>=0.3.1 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from transformers<5,>=4.4->easynmt) (0.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\pc\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from tqdm->easynmt) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11>=2.2 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fasttext->easynmt) (2.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7.0 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from fasttext->easynmt) (68.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\users\pc\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from nltk->easynmt) (8.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in c:\users\pc\appdata\roaming\python\python311\site-packages (from nltk->easynmt) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jinja2->torch>=1.6.0->easynmt) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->transformers<5,>=4.4->easynmt) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->transformers<5,>=4.4->easynmt) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->transformers<5,>=4.4->easynmt) (1.26.16)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests->transformers<5,>=4.4->easynmt) (2024.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: mpmath>=0.19 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sympy->torch>=1.6.0->easynmt) (1.3.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: fasttext
  Building wheel for fasttext (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [75 lines of output]
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:745: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.

              This deprecation is overdue, please update your project and remove deprecated
              calls to avoid build errors in the future.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\fasttext
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\FastText.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\fasttext
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\fasttext
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\fasttext\util
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\util\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\fasttext\util
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\fasttext\util
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\fasttext\tests
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\tests\test_configurations.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\fasttext\tests
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\tests\test_script.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\fasttext\tests
      copying python\fasttext_module\fasttext\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\fasttext\tests
      running build_ext
      building 'fasttext_pybind' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\python
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\python\fasttext_module
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\python\fasttext_module\fasttext
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\python\fasttext_module\fasttext\pybind
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include -IC:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include -Isrc -IC:\Users\pc\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tppython/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.obj /EHsc /DVERSION_INFO=\\\"0.9.2\\\"
      fasttext_pybind.cc
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): error C2672: 'pybind11::init': no matching overloaded function found
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1932): note: could be 'Ret pybind11::init(CFunc &&,AFunc &&)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): note: 'pybind11::init': invalid template argument for 'CFunc', type expected
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1924): note: or       'Ret pybind11::init(Func &&)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): note: 'pybind11::init': invalid template argument for 'Func', type expected
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1912): note: or       'pybind11::detail::initimpl::constructor<Args...> pybind11::init(void)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): note: 'pybind11::init': invalid template argument for 'Args', type expected
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): error C2672: 'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def': no matching overloaded function found
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1631): note: could be 'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(pybind11::detail::initimpl::pickle_factory<Args...> &&,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1625): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(pybind11::detail::initimpl::factory<Args...> &&,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1618): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(const pybind11::detail::initimpl::alias_constructor<Args...> &,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1611): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(const pybind11::detail::initimpl::constructor<Args...> &,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1599): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(const T &,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1574): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(const char *,Func &&,const Extra &...)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(171): note: 'pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::Vector>::def(const char *,Func &&,const Extra &...)': expects 3 arguments - 1 provided
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): error C2672: 'pybind11::init': no matching overloaded function found
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1932): note: could be 'Ret pybind11::init(CFunc &&,AFunc &&)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): note: 'pybind11::init': invalid template argument for 'CFunc', type expected
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1924): note: or       'Ret pybind11::init(Func &&)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): note: 'pybind11::init': invalid template argument for 'Func', type expected
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1912): note: or       'pybind11::detail::initimpl::constructor<Args...> pybind11::init(void)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): note: 'pybind11::init': invalid template argument for 'Args', type expected
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): error C2672: 'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def': no matching overloaded function found
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1631): note: could be 'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(pybind11::detail::initimpl::pickle_factory<Args...> &&,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1625): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(pybind11::detail::initimpl::factory<Args...> &&,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1618): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(const pybind11::detail::initimpl::alias_constructor<Args...> &,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1611): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(const pybind11::detail::initimpl::constructor<Args...> &,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1599): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(const T &,const Extra &...)'
      C:\Users\pc\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pybind11\include\pybind11\pybind11.h(1574): note: or       'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(const char *,Func &&,const Extra &...)'
      python/fasttext_module/fasttext/pybind/fasttext_pybind.cc(185): note: 'pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix> &pybind11::class_<fasttext::DenseMatrix>::def(const char *,Func &&,const Extra &...)': expects 3 arguments - 1 provided
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fasttext
  Running setup.py clean for fasttext
Failed to build fasttext
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fasttext, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

When things have gone this wrong – installations are failing, perhaps because of other earlier choices (or unnoticed failures) that aren't clearly remembered – it's best to start fresh, in a clean environment.

Then, gradually add back what's needed in some logical order, paying close attention (taking notes) for either the 1st indications of what's gone wrong, or what exact/minimal set of steps works.

If using Anaconda, you likely have access to the 'conda' tool for managing separate "virtual environments" that each have their own specifically-chosen set of installed packages. Use that to make a fresh environment, activate that environment, then step-by-step install what you need.

If *that* process hits errors, you'll at least have more exact information to describe how you got to the error – which would generate a StackOverflow question that might offer more-specific potential solutions.

Comment: I did as you said and started clean. Details are edited in the post.

Comment: Are you sure you started clean in a fresh, separate `conda` environment? (Your command-line shows the same `(base)` (indicator of active environment) as before.) Can you create a new non-base `conda` environment, activate it, and try just `conda install fasttext` (or `pip install fasttext` if that doesn't work), and see if it gives the same error?

Comment: Note also that in general, I don't think the official Facebook `fasttext` package claims to support Windows – only Mac & Linux are mentioned at https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/python-module.html – though I believe some people have gotten it to work (and the EasyNMT project you're using seems to show it installing at https://github.com/UKPLab/EasyNMT/issues/3) it might involve more tinkering with Windows build tools than just a simple `pip install fasttext`.

Comment: Actually, a post I read suggested I should create an environment with python 3.9 or 3.8 and install easyNMT in that environment. I did that and it went very smoothly I couldn't believe it.

Comment: Glad it's working! That's another useful thing about distinct fresh environments - rolling Python or anything else back to older compatible versions, just for your individual projects that need specifically that.